# unable to boot to source nor cloned ssd after cloning

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, clone

I screwed up and I know it.  What I need is a fix.  I had an SSD as my C drive in my HP Z420 workstation.  This is in my recording studio.  I needed to update a bunch of software and hardware so I figured I'd clone an exact copy before I did the updates in case they didn't work so I could just install the clone and be back where I was.  I used Acronis for the WD Drive (I've done it before and had no problem)  I unchecked (mistake) the shutdown after clone box and ran Acronis.  I looked like it was working and the progress window ran as it should.  After it was done, it tried to reboot with both drives still in and froze up.  When I did a hard shut down, then removed the original, it wouldn't boot up.  It gave a number of errors.  When I put the original back in it booted the first time.  After I tried to switch them out again, neither would boot.

I can plug them in to a USB port with a ext. adapter and it looks like the partitions and files are all there.  I just need to be able to boot to it.  Is there a program that will fix the boot info without deleting all of the other data on the drive?  The computer still works when I use the HDD drive that I copied the first ssd from 8 months ago, but I've done a lot since then and would like to not have to update everything individually.

I was talking with a tech from on of the copy software companies and he remoted in and looked at the drive (I connected it with a USB adapter to another computer) He did some command com stuff, changed a few things in the way the drive partitions are listed, then said he could fix it in a couple of minutes but it would cost me a couple of hundred dollars ... doesn't anyone have an idea what he could do that quick? Any help is appreciated

Comment: ↑ Please add this info to the question using the [edit] button. Adding paragraphs will make it much more readable too, now it's a huge block of text.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to boot?

Comment: It seems to be a UEFI loader issue.  That's what comes up first.  Then it goes into a Boot Agent screen with "Client MAC ADDR" a bunch of mac addr #s, with DHCP at the end and a spinning character (all in what looks like a Command Com window) - the next window is Non-system Disk or disk error